# How can I make 2 services in 2 different kubernetes clusters talk to each other securely in azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have 2 kubernetes clusters in Azure. Let's call them LegacyCluster and NewCluster. NewCluster is provisioned with Terraform.
Each has LegacyService and NewService. I need NewService to securely call LegacyService over rest. How can I do this? Is there a feature in either Kubernetes or Azure to make two networks act like one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) and\or [site-2-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways).

Networks address space have to not overlap

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably stick with network peering. This is exactly what I wanted. Nice to know about s2s VPN but I'm not sure if it's useful fo rme. I had no clue about either option. Thank you!